# How to make TFS perform a git checkout by branch name instead of sha?

Tags: git, tfs

I configured a TFS build definition to check out by branch name:

[image: tfs git config]

However, when TFS performs the checkout, it shows this:

```
Starting fetch...
Checking out 1b9d412cbab03323852e9d5d1023da51576e5a92 to D:\Builds\NC_2\14\s
Checked out branch refs/heads/cut_version for repository myapp at commit 1b9d412cbab03323852e9d5d1023da51576e5a92
```

Therefore when TFS issues the next command, `git push`, git refuses to push, since we're not on a branch:

```
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use
    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

Is there a way to get TFS to check out by the branch name instead of the sha?

Comment: Who is executing `git push`, TFS?

Comment: @CodeCaster - Yes.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Builds typically shouldn't be updating source control. It's intended to be a one-way operation.

Comment: Why is it doing that? Is it pushing artifacts? What did you configure to make it do that?

Comment: @DanielMann - It's using sbt to cut a release., So, the sbt process updates the product version number that's held in a file, and tags the release version. Both of these need to be pushed.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I added a command line operation to the TFS build definition to invoke `git push`.

Comment: Hi@DonBranson, any update on this, it could not be achieved for now. it's build sever side behavior. And *Daniel* is right it's not a recommend way to push the source control branch during build pipeline.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT - I agree - it's not the general solution. However, I've seen it widely practiced when building a push-button release cut. That's using say, Jenkins, which does support this. It seems like a reasonable way to cut a release. So maybe the question is, what's the comparable way to automate the push-button release in the TFS world?

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to do this, which is a server behavior.

> It's the VSTS service tell agent to checkout which commit, even you
>   feed in a branch name. Since VSTS need calculate changes between
>   builds, VSTS will query you git repository to get the commit hash for
>   the ref you want to build. the agent just follow what server tells it
>   to do.

In the job message agent get

```
  "build.sourceVersion": "0d3d21a150cea97f20863fcff104d03bfec50339",
  "build.sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master",
  "build.sourceBranchName": "master",
```

these info in provide by server.

More details please refer this similar issue in GitHub: [How do I Get Sources with a branch name instead of via sha?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/971)